# Should we not have a "Read-it-later" functionality?

Tags: discussion

I know, in its core Stack Exchange sites are Question/Answer sites. But I was wondering if an option would be useful for us where we could mark a question or answer or comment for reading later. And a personal list of such markings would stay with each account.

Why is that? These sites are libraries on their own. The great content management has made these sites great places for authentic articles and references. Sometimes Google points to such Stack Exchange pages which ultimately are awesome for many topics.

Sample:
I was looking into socket programming when I got this question: *[Which book(s) to learn sockets programming and TCP network communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122592/which-books-to-learn-sockets-programming-and-tcp-network-communication)*

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8122888/1928610) was useful and had good reference, but it ultimately needed a good look which I cannot give right now. This might not be the best of examples, but many times we find great list of books, nice set of commands, and myriads of how-to in such answers which ultimately act as articles.

For such cases, I'd really appreciate to just mark them for reading later. So that I do not have to keep this link in my bookmarks where it will be mixed with so many other sites and personally speaking, bookmarks aren't actually made for a reading-later function. And maintaining some kind of list in a text document on or off the cloud is just "not working".

Comment: Did you know you can create folders in your bookmarks to keep everything neatly organised?

Comment: Yes. I do maintain them that way. But what if I want the browser in my office and the one at my home to never get in sync?
And such organizing is less useful for multiple devices (Phone, Tabs, Laptop).

Comment: You can faviourate any question, by clicking the `star` below downvote, find it later in your `http://stackoverflow.com/users/<ID>/<USERNAME>?tab=favorites`

Comment: What about answers? Sometimes people give greatly useful information in comments too. Just like the one you gave, thanks :)

Comment: funny but the question you are linking to is off-topic for Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I'm wondering - "why the question has been down-voted?" Bookmarks on browser are quite a general thing and are easy to get overlooked. Favorites on the website, in my view, is however a relatively longer queue to archive 'good things' which might be looked up later. Read-it-later is a shorter queue (possibly restricted to a length like 10 so that you don't keep to much on the pile) and won't necessarily contain all 'good things'. 
I rather find @Tim's answer helpful. But would a small 'later' link beside 'share edit flag' links clutter the content too much?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've resisted doing this in a codified manner because there's so many third-party tools that do this quite well. In fact, my favorite tool for this was designed and built *right here* on Stack Exchange by some awesome folks in our Software Recommendations community. See:

*[Is there a Chrome extension that I can use to note why I've opened a tab?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1897/is-there-a-chrome-extension-that-i-can-use-to-note-why-ive-opened-a-tab)*

Just toss links to answers in the notation, or some note that leads you to what you found interesting enough to save.

The resulting extension is *very* useful for folks that  want to come back to some interesting bit, and additional tools ([Evernote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evernote), [social bookmarking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_bookmarking) tools, etc.) do such a good job at this - any stab we take at it would just be a little worse than what commonly exists.

As we look more deeply into how we show you 'all of you' as far as your contributions and achievements go - we *can* possibly revisit the idea of advanced following and favorites. I found the same desire for and utility in the idea when I learned Python using Stack Overflow, and again when I dove deeper into JavaScript without the aid of frameworks.

But, for now - I don't see us changing it any time soon.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) and the great tool. It's sad that it also means I must sync my office and home machine browsers for things to be available. But there's also a contra that, such implementation will be ultimately SE specific, so as a result might become redundant at best. I think "favorites" should also cover directly marking answers instead of only questions. That should fix my problem :) @Tim Post

Answer (score 2):

You can favorite any question, by clicking the star icon below the downvote arrow.

Favorite questions can then be found in your list of [favorites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1928610/unrealist?tab=favorites) (`http://stackoverflow.com/users/<ID>/<USERNAME>?tab=favorites`).

Comment: What about answers? Sometimes people give greatly useful information in comments too.

Comment: I know but just looking at the question, how can I be sure all of sudden which is the answer for which I marked this question? The "share" button under the answer point to the answer directly, the page opens and you are scrolled right to that answer. That functionality was implemented for a reason. Because I want to point to the answer, not the question.

Comment: And it may so happen that, I just want the answer not the question.