# Classification (or equivalent) option for favorited questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks

I ‘star’ questions (this is not about chat) for various reasons:

- **while waiting for a response to a comment**

  - Could be OP/other user forgets or does not know about `@`
  - Someone responds with one comment meant for various users and I’m not the one pinged
- **I would like to refer back to the question in the future**

  - Maybe it has interesting content but its Title does not use the keywords I would
- **I would like to refer to one specific answer in the future**

  - There may be several answers and a lot of commentary
- **I may want to return to the post for a moderation activity I don’t immediately have time for***

Now with 10M+ questions and having been a user for 3 years I have 207 Favorites despite trying to weed these out thoroughly and often.

I would find the ability to `tag` (my *own* system!) my Favorites useful. I can at present see a list of those I have starred, showing Title, tags and some other details and, to be fair, no obvious way to permit any self-classification of these on a user-by-user basis. However I know my ingenuity is no match for SE’s.

The best I can suggest at present would be to replace the indication of number of stars by question, in the Favorites view, (something of no interest to me in that view) with a number of my choice, along with something like the deleted recent items list where “my” number would match to a very short comment editable by me. I guess to work that might require that when I click to star a ‘question’ (the star may be meant by me for an *answer*!) I might need to be prompted to add ‘my’ number.

However, I don’t care how achieved nearly as much as **any easy way for me to classify stars**. For example, a button on the Favorites page to allow a .csv download, or that takes me directly to a suitable SEDE query would help.
There is also the possibility that I am overlooking some existing facility of equivalent effect. Being pointed to it would be acceptable as an answer!

I appreciate 207 is hardly “unmanageable” but this might be thousands rather than hundreds if I were able to classify them in some way – and there is no need for anything within 6-8 weeks.

This is a very similar request (unanswered): [Idea of bookmarks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252124/idea-of-bookmarks)
and this, for example (there have been many other requests for the ability to star answers)
[Revisit favorite answers feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221729/revisit-favorite-answers-feature-request) 
an issue that might be solved with my first suggestion above.
As also [Should we not have a “Read it later” functionality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268472/should-we-not-have-a-read-it-later-functionality).
Even more similar request (as kindly was drawn to my attention by [durron597](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1768232/durron597):
[Allow grouping of favorite questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125180/allow-grouping-of-favorite-questions)

---

`*` Or one where I am waiting out a delay ([see](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311424/follow-up-reminder-option-for-posts)).

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange equivalent question: [Allow grouping of favorite questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125180/allow-grouping-of-favorite-questions)

Comment: I was not intending to say "omg dupe please delete this question", I want the feature and I'm glad you're bringing attention to it. That said, I thought you should see the MSE question.

Comment: I would love to have custom tags for favourites as well, or at least some sort of search or filtering. I often favourite questions when I sense it may be an useful reference in a future discussion elsewhere. Not having a way to quickly pinpoint a favourite question among many makes using them in this way much harder.

Comment: I would just use the bookmarking feature of your browser.

Comment: @NewWorld that makes sense, I do the same... I just use that five star for temporary reason... BUT take care to record the title of the question, because who knows, maybe a day SO will change something in the urls...

Answer (score 3):

I recently wrote a user-script in response to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378147/help-me-to-remember-and-get-back-to-posts-that-i-can-improve) which has been marked as a duplicate for this question.

The user-script is called Stack Reminder, and it's essentially a bookmarking add-on for Stack Exchange sites. You can check out it out on [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/questions/8163/stack-reminder-remind-yourself-about-posts), but I will also give a breakdown about it here.

This user-script hooks to my external Stack Reminder service, which essentially works the same way as the local version, except all of the posts you put on your list will be stored in a server-side database, using an API key, instead of locally.

Using an API key means that you'll be free to use the same key on multiple devices to manage the same list, or gives you the ability to share the same list with other people.

You can install this [here](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/Userscripts/raw/master/stack_reminder.user.js).

Once this is installed, load up any page of Stack Exchange and you'll be requested to supply an API key. You can generate a free API key by going to [the Stack Reminder Backend](https://stack-reminder.grumpycrouton.com/).

Once you have supplied the key, the user-script will take care of the rest. Just click "remind me" to add a post to your list, and click "don't remind me" to remove it. (*these buttons will be near the share/edit/flag buttons under the post*)

On your left sidebar, you'll get a new entry that is labeled as "Reminders", with a count of the amount of posts on your list. If you click this, you'll get a popup which will allow you to see your list, and all of the reasons associated with posts.

---

Note: I am actively maintaining this project, feel free to submit ideas for features or reports for bugs.