# Is there a feature on Stack Overflow that let you manage your favorite questions based on categories?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, bookmarks

Currently I have 52 questions in my Favorites tab; that number is definitely going to increase in the future. Is there any feature on Stack Overflow that allows me to manage those questions based on different categories, like we can do in Gmail or Outlook? For example, I want to create a section, say "android-animation", and save all my questions related to android animation in that section.

If not can we have that feature in the near future? It might provide us a quick search for a particular category questions.

Edit 1: As @pnuts pointed out there are similar question like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305448/classification-or-equivalent-option-for-favorited-questions) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125180/allow-grouping-of-favorite-questions), they might be similar in the content but none of them have any useful answer and they are inactive for years, also in the later one @NickCraver mentioned in the comment that he is working on this feature and it will be there in the coming weeks, that was 6 years ago, so anyone has any update on that?

Comment: The favouriting system on SO is essentially useless. It's near impossible to find a specific question unless you remember the title. You would be better using your browsers bookmarking tools or a third party tool IMO.

Comment: The favouriting system is excellent for 10K users, favorite every question you think should be deleted, come back a few days later, if question is red it's already deleted, if not you can delete vote it.

Comment: Use your browser's bookmark feature.

Comment: @HansPassant Bookmark feature will work only if a person is using any browser, but what should a person do if he opened SO from SO mobile app?

Comment: @ChetanMehra Use a feature like Pocket for Firefox or a Reader app that can sync across devices. Modern phones let you download your own browser so if the one that came with your mobile device doesn't support addons or have something like Pocket, you can download and install a better one :-)

Comment: I have thousands of favorites!

Comment: Google Chrome duplicates favorites across mobile and desktop.

Comment: I think it would be cool if users could tag questions with their own private tags, that only said user sees.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for the link. Content of both questions seems to be similar, but that old question was last active 2 years back, also it does not contain any useful answer.

Answer (score 42):

### Short answer

No there's not. To quote [Turnip's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370706/is-there-a-feature-on-stack-overflow-that-let-you-manage-your-favorite-questions#comment607167_370706):

> The favouriting system on SO is essentially useless. It's near
>   impossible to find a specific question unless you remember the title.

---

### Slightly longer answer

The functionality of SO's favorites feature, IMO, is very limited. It could (and should) be improved.

I was going to point out that you could use the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/favorites-on-users) to create a more convenient way of showing your favourites. However, it turns out that a user by the name of [Anton Pantev](https://stackapps.com/users/5290/anton) has already written and [published](https://stackapps.com/questions/2438/stack-favorites-a-basic-organizer-of-your-stack-overflow-favorites) such an app.

You can view your favourites by entering your `user ID` [here](http://antonpantev.com/projects/stackfavorites/). In your case the id would be: `1725131`.

Comment: SO should then improve this feature then. For example, a flexible category/tagging system would be cool.

Comment: @Roland i was going to say the same thing :)

Comment: @Roland Agreed, I am not saying that the fact that there's already an app means that this feature/improvement request (which I happen to endorse) shouldn't be implemented. It's merely an alternative (for the time being). Additionally it would be really nice if you could open a category of these `tagged favorites` from the _flag as duplicate_ dialog. I'd most definitely flag more duplicates if I could easily find the original via some kind of 'often duplicated' category.

Comment: @Niellles, Do we require to raise any request to SO if we want to see any new feature in SO?

Comment: @ChetanMehra Adding it here with the [feature-request] tag, as you did should do it. "_This tag is for proposals of new features on the site, or requests for a change to an existing feature._"

Comment: Huh. Today I learned that my saved favorites are publicly visible.

Comment: @JonSchneider Well, it is not so bad in my opinion.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the search with

```
infavorites:mine [tagname]
```

which will show the questions for you, which you are favorizing and have the `[tagname]` tag.

For example, the questions you've favorized and belong to the `[xml]` tag, are here:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A1725131+%5Bxml%5D

<sub>You can also see others favorites on this way. The favorite "votes" are public. The query string is: `infavorites:userid`, where your user id is the number in the path variable of your user page URL.</sub>

Bookmarking these search links and sharing your bookmarks between your browsers (most of them has this functionality) will essentially do what you want.

Comment: Just in case someone gets here these days.
It seems now it is in:saves and not infavorites:mine