# Help me to remember and get back to posts that I can improve

Tags: feature-request

I use Stack Overflow a lot in work, and even though I'm most often not in answering-mode these days, every now and then I stumble upon a question that I feel I should contribute to, or even one of my own answers that needs some updating.

I can't start doing that at work, so I make a mental note and hope that I'll get to it when I get time but the problem is that there are a lot of mental notes competing of attention in my head, and I most often forget it.

It would be nice with an ability to easily mark posts in a strictly individual context, and maybe to be able to define your own custom tags/flags*. The favorite-functionality would not work for me as it's used for something completely different. That list is not supposed to be worked down to zero.

At the same time as we should avoid unnecessary functionality bloat here on Stack Overflow, I think it would be valuable for us that want to contribute but often aren't able to find the time for it. It would be neat to have an ordered to-do to work through when we eventually do find the time.

<sup>*Not to be confused with the existing functionality for tags/flags.</sup>

Comment: Favorite them? You can remove them from the list later after doing whatever you need to

Comment: @talonmies and others, Thank you for the suggestion but as I wrote the favourite-functionality would not be efficient, unless I would only use it for that. Which I don't.

Comment: @Alex Use browser bookmarks and enable bookmark syncing between your browsers at work and home.

Comment: @DanBron I like that suggestion, although I'd rather have it in the system I'm actually using. Maybe I'm overestimating how much others would find this useful?

Comment: Get to 10k, so you will see all your deleted posts.

Comment: @peterh Did you comment on the wrong post?

Comment: @Alex I've made an update to the userscript I was talking about earlier, I've added API Support so it can now be used across any amount of devices you wish. Check out the [Stackapps](https://stackapps.com/questions/8163/stack-reminder-remind-yourself-about-posts) page.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton That looks awesome, I'll definitely check it out :)

Answer (score 5):

I think you're thinking about this too hard. Open a new text file, paste in links (you can get links directly to answers through the Share link underneath them), then email it to yourself at the end of the day so you can handle them later. You can even add your own notes to each link, e.g. "Remember to edit this post for grammar" or "Try to answer this question using jQuery".

Comment: Heck, you could setup a filter to have it put in a specific mail folder.

Comment: Compared to clicking a button in SO, this requires much more work and some dedication that I don't have at the point when I need it. I know I'm lazy, but I still wan't to nudge myself to contribute more.